# ORACLE How can I select 3rd and 5th highest paid employees? ORACLE HR Scheme

Tags: sql, oracle

**I used this and it gives me the 3rd highest salary. But I need 3rd and 5th highest salaries.**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT
ROWNUM, HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY 

FROM HR.EMPLOYEES 
    JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS  ON HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
    WHERE (HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'IT' OR HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'Sales' OR HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'Finance')
    ORDER BY HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY desc
    )
    OFFSET 2 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

**I tried this after**

```
SELECT
ROWNUM, HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY,row_number() over (order by HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY desc) AS n

FROM HR.EMPLOYEES 
    JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS  ON HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
    WHERE (HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'IT' OR HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'Sales' OR HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'Finance') AND (n = 3 OR n = 5)
    ORDER BY HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY desc
```

> ORA-00904: "N": invalid identifier

**Please can anyone help me ?**

Comment: Have a look at [NTH_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions126.htm#SQLRF30031)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the where outside the subquery:

```
SELECT a.* from
(SELECT ROWNUM, HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
        HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
        row_number() over (order by HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY desc) AS n  
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES 
    JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS ON HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
    WHERE HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME in ('IT','Sales','Finance'))
) a 
where a.n in (3,5)
```

You could also simplify the query by using IN. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend it works!!! :)